# Rails nested associations (model through a model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: **Projects** which contains **Stages** which contains **Contents**.

On the Projects show.html.erb, I want to show all the Stages associated to that Project, then the Contents associated to those Stages.

So here's what I tried in **show.html.erb**:

```
<% @stages.each do |stage| %>
  <section name="concept" class="stage">
    <h3><%= stage.name %></h3>

    <% @contents.each do |content| %>
      <p><%= content.name %></p>
    <% end %>

  </section>  
<% end %>
```

And here's what's in my **projects_controller.rb**

```
def show
    project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @stages = project.stages

    stage = Stage.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @contents = stage.contents
  end
```

Here's **stage.rb** model:

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    belongs_to :project
    has_many :contents
end
```

And here's **contents.rb**:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stage
end
```

The error that I'm getting is:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: stages.slug: SELECT "stages".* FROM "stages" WHERE "stages"."slug" = 'pulse' ORDER BY "stages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Extracted source (around line #16):

```
stage = Stage.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

**EDIT**: The issue is it's looking for a Stage with the id of the project, not the ID of the stage. I'm trying to get the Stage that it's showing and then iterate over each of its Contents that belong to it.

Comment: Why are you finding by `params[:id]` with both stage and project in the projects controller?  You've gone to `/projects/pulse` which then uses friendly id to find the correct project but you don't have a stage with a slug of pulse.  What are you trying to do on line 16?

Comment: On Line 16 I'm trying to get the Stage and send back its Contents

Comment: But you don't have one stage, you have many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects controller:

```
def show
  @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @stages = @project.stages.includes(:contents)
end
```

View:

```
<% @stages.each do |stage| %>
  <section name="concept" class="stage">
    <h3><%= stage.name %></h3>

    <% stage.contents.each do |content| %>
      <p><%= content.name %></p>
    <% end %>

  </section>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [friendly_id docs](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Example_Setup) you have to run a migration that adds the `slug` column to your Stage model. Make sure you've done this and run `rake db:migrate`.

This is what the error is saying:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: stages.slug

You haven't added that column to the stages table yet.

You have to give it the id of the stage. In your code you're using the same id in both finds:

```
project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
@stages = project.stages

stage = Stage.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

You're using `params[:id]` twice. There must be some other params you could use, maybe `params[:stage_id]` assuming you set up nested routes. Typically though, the parent model would have `params[:project_id]` and the `params[:id]` would be the id of the nested stage model.

Comment: The issue is it's looking for a Stage with the id of the project, not the ID of the stage.